# How to make a Clickable link within dataframe inside Streamlit

Tags: python, dataframe, hyperlink, streamlit

I am trying to make one of the column clickable in streamlit but it returns with some additional unrelated information which makes it unreachable to its destination. basically it is a stock data and when clicked in the symbol that symbol chart was supposed to be opened.

Another issue is with

```
df.to_html
```

Table is not sortable.

I want to make link to work and table to be sortable.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')


def make_clickable(link):
    text = link.split(',')[0]
    link = 'https://nepsealpha.com/trading/chart?symbol='+df['Symbol']
    print(text)
    return f"<a target='_blank' href='{link}'>{text}</a>"


df['Symbol'] = df['Symbol'].apply(make_clickable)

st.write(df.to_html(escape=False, index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [st.dataframe](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.dataframe) instead of st.write you can configure your columns.
One of the options is [st.column_config.LinkColumn()](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.column_config/st.column_config.linkcolumn)

You can do something like:

```
st.dataframe(df, column_config={"Link_Column": st.column_config.LinkColumn()}
```

An example:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'Website': ['https://www.example.com',
                'https://www.google.com',
                'https://www.openai.com']
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.dataframe(df, column_config={"Website": st.column_config.LinkColumn()})
```

Comment: I could not make it work with st.dataframe(df, column_config={"Link_Column": st.column_config.LinkColumn()}

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, here is a full workable example
```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'Website': ['https://www.example.com',
                'https://www.google.com',
                'https://www.openai.com']
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.dataframe(df, column_config={"Website": st.column_config.LinkColumn()})
```

Comment: We don't want to display the website. what we need is to make the Name column to be clickable so that if a user clicks on John then https://www.example.com is executed and similarly if we click on Alice then https://www.google.com' should open.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to map the links to the corresponding names and then write the dataframe in html using [`df.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html), but you should sort df first before proceeding with the operation.
Note I'm using [Mojca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76543783/19290081) data to demonstrate:

```py
data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'Website': ['https://www.example.com',
                'https://www.google.com',
                'https://www.openai.com']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#You first sort df by Name
df = df.sort_values(by='Name')
df['Name'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(row['Website'], row['Name']),
    axis=1)

# You can choose to drop the Website column
df = df.drop('Website', axis=1)

st.write(df.to_html(escape=False, index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

---

[image]